# Is there a set of rules for newer members?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

How much greeting, editing and suggesting should a newbie be doing? I just got 1000 points. I can edit and vote on some subjects. I do not wish to step on toes or take on more that the regulars feel is appropriate. I also am not sure about answering or voting up or down on posts from before I started on this stack.

I could and would be happy to say Welcome!" -- but should I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do whatever you feel comfortable with.

Seriously.

You've earned those privileges so feel free to use them.  If you aren't sure how you should be using them, maybe hang back and look at how other people use their moderation privileges.  You can always ask here on meta if you need guidance.

As long as what you do is beneficial to the site, you will be fine.  And for most moderation activities, other people need to agree with your actions before they actually happen (like voting to close, etc.).  And if you do something that is wrong, it's usually pretty easy to fix.

Short answer: don't worry too much.  Go forth and make the site better.  Read the help pages on your new privileges and ask any questions on Meta.

Comment: so it isn't weird to welcome someone when I am also new? I love the site, so plan on participating.

Comment: @WillowRex It's not weird at all.  Just because you are new doesn't mean you can't be welcoming and friendly :)

Comment: great and thanks!

Comment: I totally agree, in fact sometimes it can be more welcoming to have it come from someone with medium rep rather than a high rep person.